# Looking for a shed for packages/drop off shed for deliveries

Tags: shed

While house hunting one of the homes had a shed that had a swinging door like a trash can at the top. At the bottom it had a larger door that had a lock on it, so you can remove the packages. I'm not sure if this is something that I can buy or if I have to DIY part or all of it. I have only found mini sheds where the whole front opens. [image: drawing from memory; may be smaller than what I wrote]

Comment: Search for a theft proof package mail box, rather than a shed.

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is.

Comment: Libraries have some analogue also.

Answer (score 1):

Order up one of those clothing/shoes dropboxes - those are certainly mass-produced. Whatever box you pick will have some limit on size of package it will take, and this type will subject the packages to a drop.

If the entry will accept large packages, it's also subject to package thieves crawling inside to lift packages back out.

For limited volume, a simple shed or box with a lock (or a "lock per door" on several compartments to accommodate several separate deliveries) that's unlocked in the morning, and you request the driver to place packages in and click the lock upon delivery will work without the drop, IF the delivery driver does not simply ignore the instructions (it happens.)

[image]
[Image source](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/clothing-shoes-donation-box-pink-collection-houston-texas-suburbs-sign-side-indicates-accepted-as-156448534.jpg)